# Characterize the values of A and B for which variety is singular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity

Let $A, B ∈ \overline{K}$ with $K$ a field. Characterize the values of A and B for which each of the following variety is singular:

$V : Y^2 Z + AXY Z + BY Z^2 = X^3$

Looking at the point where partial derivatives vanish, we have (0,0,0) is always a singular point, which means that for any pair $(A,B)\in \overline{K}^2$, V is singular. Is that correct?

Thank you for any help or hint.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm sure you're talking about a projective curve (single homogeneous equation in $X,Y,Z$) whose points lie in the projective plane. Note that the point $(0,0,0)$ does not belong to the projective plane.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that  (0,0,0) does not belong to the projective plan. Could you please advise why V is a projective variety. There is no mention of it in my textbook (Silvermann Arithmetic of elliptic curves)

Comment: Its a homogeneous polynomial in X,Y,Z.